# Best way to address "cannot read property * of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

This error comes up a lot in javascript development.

> cannot read property join of undefined

Is there a best way of dealing with this issue?

Some of the techniques I've used are:

**Initialisation**

```
question.tags = question.tags || [];
console.log(question.tags.join(', ');
```

**If statements**

```
if(question.tags) {
  console.log(question.tags.join(', ');
}
```

Comment: The “best way” entirely depends on the purpose of your program and the data.

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if..else`, `Object.hasOwnProperty()`, `Array.isArray()` to determine if `question` exists and object has property `tags` and `question.tags` is an array

```
if (typeof question === "object" 
    && question.hasOwnProperty("tags") 
    && Array.isArray(question.tags)) {
  //do stuff
} else {
  // do other stuff, e.g
  // question = {};
  // question.tags = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific and exact way to do it. If there is an instance of the Array or Object or String, it inhertits the prototypal functions. Like an instance of array has a splice(), String instance has a replace ().

Now when this instance is undefined, it throws JS error. Lets assume `a` is supposedly an array. You can put a dirty check either by a logical ||

```
(a || []).length;
```

or a if block or a ternary property

```
return a ? a.length || undefined;
```

or a type check

```
(Array.isArray(a) || []).length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
question.tags ? question.tags : []
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use === and !== operators in if condition like

```
  if(object.property !== undefined)
     {
       ///write your code here
      }
```

This operator will match your value + type so its easy to identify if mentioned property is undefined or not..hope this will help:)